# Unable to modify the Java codes

Tags: java, eclipse, output

I am new to Java and I found something super weird. I imported a project into my eclipse and tried to made some changes to it.

However, no matter what I did the output of the project remained the same even after I commented out the entire Main class.

Anyone has a clue why this is happening ?

Comment: Are you compiling the code? I would select "Build Automatically" from the options so that you don't forget.

Comment: have you tried a restart of eclipse ? which eclipse are you using and wich release ?

Comment: Yes, I tried everything above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that your project cannot built due to some critical problem (missing required library, unable to write to the output directory, etc.). Please check "Errors/Warnings" view, there should be some hint.

Comment: There were some jar files with false path. After I deleted them, everything works fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you had compiled classes in the target directory. Do a `Project` > `Clean` before you run.

Comment: Problem Solved Thank you